# I Am facing issue on WebSocket Connectivity and Response not getting after send message

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

Error on Websocket Connection, sometime it's connected and already connection established and not getting response after connection

```
try
            {
               // Initialize ClientWebSocket instance and connect with Url
               _ws = new ClientWebSocket();
                if (headers != null)
                {
                    foreach (string key in headers.Keys)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("_wsheaders " + key + ": " + headers[key]);
                        _ws.Options.SetRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
                    }
                }
              
                _ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri(_url), CancellationToken.None).Wait();

                if (_ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    try
                    {
                        _ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ping")), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
                        Console.WriteLine("------Result-------------");
                        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_ws));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        OnError?.Invoke("Error while sending data. Message:  " + e.Message);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with the code you provided, I can't confirm where your problem is, because you didn't explain how to connect and other logic. But in any case, you can refer to [Microsoft's official example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sample-app), it is a very basic example.

When you are connecting, you need to use the corresponding url to instantiate the `WebSocket`:

```
connectButton.onclick = function() {
    //...
    socket = new WebSocket(connectionUrl.value);
    //...
}
```

Then call the `AcceptWebSocketAsync` method to upgrade the TCP connection to a WebSocket connection, using the `WebSocket` object to send and receive messages:

```
if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
{
    using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
    //...
}
```

When sending and receiving messages, you need to call `SendAsync` and `ReceiveAsync` (in asynchronous cases):

```
await webSocket.SendAsync(
    new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count),
    receiveResult.MessageType,
    receiveResult.EndOfMessage,
    CancellationToken.None);

receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(
    new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
```

Of course, this also contains a lot of logical relationships, you can check [this article](https://sahansera.dev/understanding-websockets-with-aspnetcore-5/) combined with [Microsoft's official examples](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/websockets/samples) for more details.

Hope this can help you.